# Sequence of comparisons of different columns and add a string to a new column based on comparison

Tags: python, pandas

Comparing one pair of columns and result as enum to new columns and compare other pair of column and need the result as enum to the same new column

The df is as shown:

```
a   b   c   d   length
18  32  76  75  8
64  63  76  64  9
55  84  98  45  0
72  92  87  65  0
76  83  23  56  0
36  87  97  12  11
```

As shown in the dummy dataframe I am comparing columns in sequence

1. filtering if b > a
2. filtering if d > c
3. filtering if length is 0

My code is as follows,

```
df['status_flag'] = np.where(df['b']>=df['a'], "Filtered out based on b>a", None)
df['status_flag'] = np.where(df['d']>=df['c'], "Filtered out based on b>a", None)
df['status_flag'] = np.where(df['e']==0, "Filtered out based on length", None)
```

this yeild output as:

```
a   b   c   d   length      new
18  32  76  75  8       
64  68  76  94  9       
55  84  98  99  0       "Filtered out based on length"
72  92  87  65  0       
76  83  23  56  0       "Filtered out based on length"
36  87  97  100 11
```

basically it replaces existing strings with None. How to do this in a different way.

expected output:

```
a   b   c   d   length      new
18  32  76  75  8       "Filtered out based on b>a"
64  68  76  94  9       "Filtered out based on d>c"
55  84  98  99  0       "Filtered out based on length"
72  92  87  65  0       "Filtered out based on d>c"
76  83  23  56  0       "Filtered out based on length"
36  87  97  100 11      "Passed all filters"
```

Comment: And why doesn't row 3 produces *Filtered out based on length* ?

Comment: row 3? it does produces. But it replaces previous strings if exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish this with the following:

```
# Apply filters in the reverse order to get the sequence you want
df['new'] = 'Passed all filters'
df.loc[df.b > df.a, 'new'] = 'Filtered out based on b>a'
df.loc[df.d > df.c, 'new'] = 'Filtered out based on d>c'
df.loc[df.length == 0, 'new'] = 'Filtered out based on length'
print(df)
```

```
    a   b   c   d  length                           new
0  18  32  76  75       8     Filtered out based on b>a
1  64  63  76  64       9            Passed all filters
2  55  84  98  45       0  Filtered out based on length
3  72  92  87  65       0  Filtered out based on length
4  76  83  23  56       0  Filtered out based on length
5  36  87  97  12      11     Filtered out based on b>a
```

Note: this uses the first data frame given, which differs from the one used in your example. Using that one gives the following result:

```
    a   b   c    d  length                           new
0  18  32  76   75       8     Filtered out based on b>a
1  64  68  76   94       9     Filtered out based on d>c
2  55  84  98   99       0  Filtered out based on length
3  72  92  87   65       0  Filtered out based on length
4  76  83  23   56       0  Filtered out based on length
5  36  87  97  100      11     Filtered out based on d>c
```